# Reduce the distance % subtracted as window shrinks CSS only

Tags: css, view, responsive-design, resize

For example i have this centered element with `margin-top: -10%;`

and i want on resize, more the window shrinks less that % become (like -6%).

I know of **vw** and **vh**, but those almost don't change at all on window resize if the distance we're working with is something small.

Is there a way with some `margin-top: calc();` maybe with `*` doing some weird math trick to achieve what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

For wide window, I added a media query. **I used 1300px as an example.** If the window is resized to larger than 1300px, the margin will be constant.

**When the window starts to shrink below 1300px, the margin starts to change radically.** I achieved this with this calculation:

`margin-top: calc(-30px + 1300px - 100vw);`

As you can see, at 1300px the margin will be exactly the same as if it would be bigger and it would use the media query, because

- I subtracted the original margin,
- then I added the breakpoint width (=1300px),
- and then subtracted the window width which is exactly the same in that moment (=1300px).

So basically we use that as the "starting point". **From then on, the more the window shrinks, the more radically the margin will go in the positive direction**, because the shrinking width is negated in the equation. *(Meaning, we increasingly negate less as the window shrinks.)*

---

#### Play with it here to figure to achieve your own ideal numbers:

https://codepen.io/bradib0y/pen/xyzJYE

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear at all my answer, cause i got confused as well while writing it, i edited the title and text.

Comment: I edited the answer. I hope it will help. Good luck for finding your own numbers for the solution.